# strange error in compiling small c++ code

Tags: c++

I tried to compile the following code, but it fails:

```
#include <iostream>

    int main(){
    double conveter, temp=25;

    conveter = (temp – 32.0) * 5.0/9.0;
    std::cout<<conveter;
        return 0;
    }
```

with this error:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '–'

Any advise please?

Comment: your `-` might be unicode

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: The `–` is indeed a U+2013 symbol. The minus sign is U+002D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong minus sign, type the minus sign again, then it works perfectly. Unicode...

You `–` -> me `-`

Answer (score 3):

You've somehow ended up with a Unicode "en dash" character instead of an ASCII `-`.

Make sure you're using a plain text editor not a word processor; delete and retype the dash; and be careful where you copy and paste code from.